# Problem in adding SDK location for android studio in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-sdk

I have tried to install the android studio by [this site instruction](https://newbedev.com/how-to-install-android-sdk-on-ubuntu?__cf_chl_managed_tk__=pmd_7RT.bYB4GzhoM0hhI_iDbFHgWD5u0wtshCjm2vT2W.c-1634847456-0-gqNtZGzNAxCjcnBszQgl) and below commands, the android studio show warning sigh and don't  add this path to the android studio:

```
sudo apt install android-sdk

sudo apt install android-studio
```

and added the below content to `~/bashrc` file :

```
# Export the Android SDK path 
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

# Fixes sdkmanager error with java versions higher than java 8
export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
```

and tried to add the SDK, but I get the below error by manually adding the SDK files locations:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQV74.png)

Also, by installing the SKD downloading the SDK file from [this address](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip) and unzip it  and give the location don't fixed as you can see at above photo. also, it can not recognize the **sdkmanager** as you can see below:

```
so-pc@sopc-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~$ sdkmanager --list

sdkmanager: command not found
$ sudo /usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update 
sudo: /usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager: command not found
```

I guess It must remove the android studio and install it again, but I asked here to have some comment about the reason or. also, I have added the path to `~/bashrc` file and restarted the PC, but it doesn't solve.

**Update 1:**

Also in the downloaded **sdk folder** form [this link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip), by running the **sdkmanager** it give the below error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohYKM.png)

```
so-pc@sopc-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15IKB:~/Downloads/Trash/sdk-tools-linux-4333796/tools/bin$ ./sdkmanager --update
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.se.ee not found
```

Thanks.

Comment: Android Developers' official site provides [a standard installation process for Linux](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux). Maybe some steps may give you some hints on what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

I see overcomplication in both question and method.

You have to use simpler method which involves [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make), install package from it

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake android
```

the last command will install Android Studio to your home folder with corresponding shortcuts.